biblioshiny(), Error: arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 322
open R (not R studio) and run the following code
library(bibliometrix)
biblioshiny()

opened browser and imported data from Web of Science, .bib file and everything ok
but when I imported the .bib file from the Scopus database with 325 documents, the message appeared:
Error: arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 322
Could it be that the Scopus database that was compatible can no longer be viewed in the browser with biblioshiny()?
Can anyone tell me how to do this?


information on how to run a .bib file from the Scopus database
